# App Logging using facebook sdk last version

Tags: android, facebook

Please I want to login using facebook sdk last version
I tried a lot to follow steps in facebook tutorials but it does not succeed
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? This question is very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explaining each and every step to integrate facebook sdk in android app is bit vague.May be you can refere this link from [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) which gives you basic implementation.
Another useful link from [parse.com](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-android) or even you can follow [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_facebook_integration.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [This Library(Simple Facebook)](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook), so easy and straight forward.